# gpg2 --edit-key addphoto / keytocard without password prompt

Tags: bash, gnupg, cryptography, smartcard, openpgp

I am trying export subkeys to card for a keyring without any keyboard interaction using the command `keytocard`. This type of command is the same as `addphoto` as it requires to edit the keyring with `--edit-key`

The following code add a photo but password is still required:

```
local cmd="addphoto\n$var_photo_path\ny\nsave"
echo -e $cmd | gpg2  --command-fd 0 --status-fd 2 --edit-key $keyring_hash_id
```

I have tried several approach around:
  [gpg asks for password even with --passphrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with)

I also took into account the option:

```
--pinentry-mode loopback
```

as explained here:
  [wiki.archlinux.org:GnuPGUnattended_passphrase](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Unattended_passphrase)

I use Ubuntu with and gpg 2.1.15 with libgcrypt 1.7.2-beta

Anyone knows how avoid any keyboard interaction on these type of command `addphoto` / `keytocard` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for `addphoto`:

```
cmd="addphoto\n$var_photo_path\ny\nPASSPHRASE\nquit\ny\n" 
echo -e "$cmd" | gpg2  --command-fd 0 --pinentry-mode=loopback --status-fd 2 --edit-key "$keyid"
```